# How do long term halal loans work with inflation in Islam?

Tags: quran, halal-haram, sunni, riba, loan

I have a series of questions about Islamic loans.  My first question is this:

If person 1 loans 100k to person 2 and creates a contract which states that the agreed payback date is 25 years from now.  How much does person 2 pay back person 1?

We all know that the value of money reduces due to inflation.  For example, 35 years ago, my dad bought a house for 5k, now to buy a similar house you have to pay 200k.

So my question is, should inflation be taken into account according to Islam?

What confuses me is that if person 1 is only entitled to 100k after the 25 years, he will in effect be at a huge disadvantage, i.e. in real terms, he will not get back what he loaned person 2.

At the same time, if person 2 gives back person 1 more than 100k, that is potentially interest which is haraam.

So just to clarify, how do long-term halaal loans work in Islam when it comes to inflation?

Comment: See also the answer to this related question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5301/is-making-an-equivalent-value-loan-in-accord-with-islam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is not permissible for the one who borrows money from anyone to
>   commit himself to repaying the loan based on the value of the currency
>   at the time when the loan is repaid, rather he must repay the loan
>   with the same value as it had at the time he took it.

I thought that was an extremely clear sentence from [this fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/95515/inflation) which goes into a lot more detail to answer this question.

Answer (score -1):

There are two main concepts that you need to understand for this question:

- Islam understands the time/value of money (depreciates over time)
- Most economies today are inflationary (the value of your money shrinks over time)

When you put these two concepts together, the answer becomes quite simple: if you make a long-term loan, that ends up being repaid over several years, **you need to go to a qadi (judge) to evaluate the amount to pay back.**

If you don't live somewhere with a qadi, you might have a problem resolving this. But you need to be very careful, because if you yourself try to assess this, you can fall under the rulings of riba very easily -- loaning out $100k and getting paid back $101k.

Wallahu a'lam.

**Source:** Weekend intensive course on Islamic Finance